# ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR with Let's Encrypt on specific devices

Tags: android, google-chrome, ssl, lets-encrypt, traefik

I've deployed a web app using Traefik with Let's Encrypt certificates.

Site works without any issues on all of my devices, with SSL enabled.

I am getting reports from my client  that they are unable to access the site (`ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` in Chrome) from their company contract Android phones. They have confirmed the site is accessible from their desktop devices, as well as personal phones.

Without any way of reproducing this myself, I'm at a  bit of a loss as to how to proceed.

What should I be looking at in this scenario? Is there feasibly much I can do myself, or does this seem to be entirely on their network?

I suspect the Let's Encrypt CA isn't being accepted on their devices, but I am not quite sure yet what exactly is the problem in their environment, or if there is anything I can change to make these certificates be accepted.

I'm seeing nothing at all to explain it in the Traefik logs.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned it is possible that they are not accepting the Let's Encrypt CA,
but without additional information it is impossible to diagnose.

My first step would be to check if they are able to access other sites that use the Let's Encrypt CA, if they are unable you know the root cause of this issue is the acceptance of the CA itself.

If it is just your site, it is possible a network setting is improperly routing to your site causing the SSL failure.

Comment: Client is now reporting their devices are accessing the site without any trouble. I haven't changed anything, they haven't changed anything. Possibly something automated in their network security then, but at this point neither of us have any idea, and their IT team isn't in... been a strange morning, if I ever get to know the root cause, or it comes back, I'll post an update/answer here.